# System.Net.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode not encoding #

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need to encode a url in my WP7 application. The class im using dosent seem to encode `#` (to `%23`). Any ideas what im doing wrong?

```
string foo = InkBunnyUrls.Login + "&username=" + txtUsername.Text + "&password=" + txtPassword.Password;
//foo = https://inkbunny.net/api_login.php?output_mode=xml&username=test&password=foobar#1
string url = System.Net.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(foo);
// url = https://inkbunny.net/api_login.php?output_mode=xml&amp;username=test&amp;password=foobar#1
```

**Edit**: I tried UrlEncode and that dosent work (see below). Reading the msdn doc it wont escape # . I  cant use the system.web class as it isnt in WP7

```
        string foo = InkBunnyUrls.Login + "&username=" + txtUsername.Text + "&password=" + txtPassword.Password;
        //foo = https://inkbunny.net/api_login.php?output_mode=xml&username=test&password=foobar#1
        string url = Uri.EscapeUriString(foo);
        //  https://inkbunny.net/api_login.php?output_mode=xml&username=test&password=foobar#1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `#` symbol doesn't need to be HTML-encoded.

If you're expecting the result to be `%23` then you should look at [`UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) instead:

```
string encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("#");    // "%23"
```

**EDIT...**

Do the WP7 libs support [`EscapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx)?

```
string encoded = Uri.EscapeDataString("#");    // "%23"
```

Comment: @Tom: Edited with an alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httputility.urlencode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and not HtmlEncode.